# Buttons in SwiftUI List ForEach view trigger even when not "tapped"?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
struct ButtonTapTest: View {
    
    let items = [1, 2, 3]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                CellTestView()
            }
        }
        
    }
}


struct CellTestView:View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button {
                print("TOP")
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            .border(.red)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                print("BOTTOM")
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "play")
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            .border(.yellow)
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Creates the following screen:

[image]

Problem:

**Both button actions get triggered in the cell regardless of where I tap on the `CellTestView`**. I want the individual button actions to trigger separately, each only when its button gets tapped, and not when I tap outside anywhere else on the cell.

You can see in the gif below that it does not matter where I tap on the `CellTestView`, both button actions get trigger regardless where on the view I tap, and both "TOP" and "BOTTOM" logs trigger at the same time.

How can I fix this so the two buttons in the cell receive the tap independently and only when the tap is inside the related button?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whenever you have multiple buttons in a list row, you need to manually set the button style to `.borderless` or `.plain`. This is because buttons “adapt” to their context.
According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/primitivebuttonstyle/automatic):

> If you create a button inside a container, **like a [List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list)**, the style resolves to the recommended style for buttons inside that container for that specific platform.

So when your button is in a List, its tap target extends to fill the row and you get a highlight animation. SwiftUI isn’t smart enough to stop this side effect when you have more than 2 buttons, so you need to set [`buttonStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/buttonstyle(_:)-7qx1) manually.

```
CellTestView()
    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
```

Result:

[image: Tapping top and bottom button results in separate print statements]

Comment: so, why is this? I want to understand the reason why this works. Do we need to modify a cell view with `.buttonStyle(.borderless)` modifier all the time to make buttons work or is this an exception? Can you elaborate as to why this works?

Comment: @zumzum see my edit

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this problem is to wrap each button in its own VStack or HStack.

Answer (score 0):

when you have a list, tapping on a list row will trigger both buttons.
Try this code to make each "button" equivalent, trigger separately.

```
struct CellTestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "play.fill") .font(.system(size: 40)).foregroundColor(.red).border(.red)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("-----> playFill \(playFill)")
                }
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "play") .font(.system(size: 40)).foregroundColor(.red).border(.yellow)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("--> play \(play)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside list items, use this modifier:

```
 .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

Like this:

```
  ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
    CellTestView()
   .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())

  }
```