# SwiftUI changing one element in an array changes all elements in the array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to change the color of a button when it's pressed. It works as intended in the preview of WordleRowView.swift but when I press a button in WordleView.swift, every button in that row changes color.

WordleView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

class WordleRow: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var word: String
    @Published var colors: [Color] = [.gray, .gray, .gray, .yellow, .green]
    
    init(_ word: String) {
        self.word = word
    }
}

class WordleBoard: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var rows = [WordleRow]()
    
    init() {
        self.rows = [
            WordleRow("hello"),
            WordleRow("horse")
        ]
    }
}

struct WordleView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var board = WordleBoard()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(board.rows) { wordleRow in
                        WordleRowView(wordleRow: wordleRow)
                    }
                    .onDelete { board.rows.remove(atOffsets: $0) }
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
                Button("Solve") {
                    print(board.rows[0].colors)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    WordleView()
}
```

WordleRowView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct WordleRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var wordleRow: WordleRow
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            LetterBox(wr: wordleRow, idx: 0)
            LetterBox(wr: wordleRow, idx: 1)
            LetterBox(wr: wordleRow, idx: 2)
            LetterBox(wr: wordleRow, idx: 3)
            LetterBox(wr: wordleRow, idx: 4)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

#Preview {
    WordleRowView(wordleRow: WordleRow("hello"))
}

struct LetterBox: View {
    @ObservedObject var wr: WordleRow
    
    let idx: Int
    
    var letter: String {
        String(wr.word[wr.word.index(wr.word.startIndex, offsetBy: idx)])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(letter) {
            switch wr.colors[idx] {
            case .gray:
                wr.colors[idx] = .yellow
            case .yellow:
                wr.colors[idx] = .green
            default:
                wr.colors[idx] = .gray
            }
            
            print(idx)
            print(wr.colors)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .background(wr.colors[idx])
    }
}
```

I've tried using a dictionary instead of an array to store colors but the same problem occurs.

Comment: One thing is that you should use  StateObject and not ObservedObject in WordleView but I don’t know if this change will affect your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the console logs that the action for every button is firing when you use the `WordleView` preview, but not when you use the `WordleRowView` preview. The difference between these two is that you have a `List` in `WordleView`, and multiple buttons in a list row for some reason don't work properly unless you apply a style (see [Buttons in SwiftUI List ForEach view trigger even when not "tapped"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399810/buttons-in-swiftui-list-foreach-view-trigger-even-when-not-tapped) for another example).

Applying `.buttonStyle(.plain)` in `LetterBox` fixes your issue.